# Adding each variables in the class together using reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

Is there a way to add each variables using reflection? For example, the manual way of doing it is:

```
public class PlayerStats {
    public float Health;
    public float HealthRegen;
    public float Mana;
    public float ManaRegen;
    public float Stamina;
    public float StaminaRegen;
    public float Armor; 
    public float AttackDamage;
    public float AttackDamageCritical;
    public float AttaackSpeed;
    public float AttackRange;
    public float MovementSpeed;

    public static PlayerStats operator +(PlayerStats ps1, PlayerStats ps2){
        PlayerStats returnPlayerStats = new PlayerStats();
        returnPlayerStats.Health = ps1.Health + ps2.Health;
        returnPlayerStats.HealthRegen = ps1.HealthRegen + ps2.HealthRegen;
        returnPlayerStats.Mana = ps1.Mana + ps2.Mana;
        returnPlayerStats.ManaRegen = ps1.ManaRegen + ps2.ManaRegen;
        returnPlayerStats.Stamina = ps1.Stamina + ps2.Stamina;
        returnPlayerStats.StaminaRegen = ps1.StaminaRegen + ps2.StaminaRegen;
        returnPlayerStats.Armor = ps1.Armor + ps2.Armor;
            returnPlayerStats.AttackDamage = ps1.AttackDamage + ps2.AttackDamage;
        returnPlayerStats.AttackDamageCritical = ps1.AttackDamageCritical + ps2.AttackDamageCritical;
        returnPlayerStats.AttaackSpeed = ps1.AttaackSpeed + ps2.AttaackSpeed;
        returnPlayerStats.Health = ps1.AttackRange + ps2.AttackRange;
        returnPlayerStats.Health = ps1.MovementSpeed + ps2.MovementSpeed;
        return returnPlayerStats;
    }
}
```

So I was thinking can I automate this by using reflection? Maybe something like:

```
foreach(var field in typeof(PlayerStats).getFields()){
    field.setValue((object)((int)field.getValue(ps1) + (int)field.getValue(ps2)))
}
```

Comment: You'd be pushing actual run time work into the code simply to avoid some typing. If this is that painful for you, you can probably write some T4 templates to generate this for you.

Comment: You could push it further and use Expression Trees to generate the code at runtime, but just once, before method is called for the first time. Is it worth it? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are better off leaving it the way it is, as reflection is  much slower than normal access, and its a bad idea to include it in operators as they may be used in loops etc, but if you want to achieve a similar effect do the following:

Use a Dictionary seeing as your fields are all floats, then you can add a method to

```
private Dictionary<string,float> fields = new Dictionary<string,float>()

public PlayerStats()
{
    fields.Add("Health", value);
    // other fields here 
}

public void SetField(string name, float value)
{
     if(!fields.ContainsKey(name))
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Field doesnt exists");
     fields[name] = value;
}
```

Your class could have a default set of fields which you can add to.

The + operator method would loop through the dictionary keys and sum the values on both objects.

```
public static PlayerStats operator +(PlayerStats ps1, PlayerStats ps2){
    var playerstats = new PlayerStats();
    foreach(var key in fields.keys)
    {
      playerstats[key] = ps1[key] + ps2[key];
    }
    return playerstats;
}
```

You can add strongly typed accessor's as properties

```
public float Health
{
     get { return fields["Health"]; }
     set { field["Health"] = value; }
}
```